# How do I make a text input non-editable and secure?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I do know about the `<input type="text" readonly />` possibilaty. However, this is not secure. Let's say I have an input field where it's important that people cannot edit it. With readonly people can just go to inspect and delete that from the input and it will be edit-able. Is there a way to do this where users cannot change it in any way?

Comment: No, you can't. A user will always be able to modify the dom. If you don't want the user to change the value, you should use something else serverside, like sessions

Comment: @Xtroy that can also just be deleted in the inspect window (f12)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No there is not.** The user can send **any** GET and POST variables he wants. You have to validate the user input in your php script (I assume you use php because of the used tags)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And yes I do use PHP, simply didn't think of that way of doing it. I will go do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can before sending your form, validate it with javascript (but it can be disabled too), so better solution validate your form on action form handler, like a filter.